# Merging factor with non-factor in data.table leads to unexpected results

Tags: r, merge, data.table, factors

Merging two data.tables by a common column, where in one data.table the merge column is a factor and in the other it is not creates unexpected results.  No warning or error is thrown, and the problem has strange implications for the underlying data.tables involved.

```
require(data.table)
##Create two tiny data.tables.
data <- data.table(Country=c("Afghanistan","Albania","Western Europe"),Value =c(1,2,100))
data
## Country          Value
## 1    Afghanistan     1
## 2        Albania     2
## 3 Western Europe   100 

NatName <-data.table(Country =factor(c("Afghanistan","Albania")),code=c("AFG","ALB"))


NatName
##Country       code
##1 Afghanistan  AFG
##2     Albania  ALB

##Merge them together.
merge(data,NatName,by="Country",all.x=TRUE)

##       Country Value code
##1:          NA   100   NA
##2: Afghanistan     1  AFG
##3:     Albania     2  ALB
```

That's strange, what happened to the Western Europe?  The merge killed the Country name.  Oh well, minor inconvenience. But wait, there is more.

```
##Lets try setting keys first.
setkey(data, Country)
setkey(NatName,Country)
merge(data,NatName,by="Country",all.x=TRUE)
##       Country Value code
##1:          NA   100   NA
##2: Afghanistan     1  AFG
##3:     Albania     2  ALB
##Same results.  But, lets look at our data.
data
##         Country Value
##1    Afghanistan   100
##2        Albania     1
##3 Western Europe     2
```

Gulp. The values are wrong.  Western Europe = 100, not 2... Something changed my original data table.

Of course, this begins with a user error.  The columns should be the same type for a merge.  I came across it when I tried merging a data table with a CSV that I read using read.csv.  Since I did not set stringsAsFactor=FALSE, one DT had factors the other did not.

Maybe merge should check and warn?  In case you are curious: my session info.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.1    Rcpp_0.11.2   reshape2_1.4  stringr_0.6.2 tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your first error, but the second one is weird indeed. Especially the last part where `data` was entirely changed... Try [version 1.9.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) maybe this behaviour been fixed already

Comment: all.X=TRUE needs to be set in the merge for the first error.  Its corrected above.

Comment: For even more 'fun' try `NatName[data]` or `data[NatName]`. The same has happened to me in pretty much the same context quite often, so I try hard to remember to keep both in character form. As you say, a warning would be good though.

Comment: I think this is [#499](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/499) which is not fixed yet. In general, it would be great to check the issues page before posting on potential bugs.

Comment: The second part of the bug seems novel. But, point taken, I'll be sure to check there first.  This package is very useful, and I don't want to discourage people from using it.

Comment: Thanks. The second part is not reproducible for me (on v1.9.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to close the open question.
The issue #499 related to merging on character-factor variables has been fixed. The issue in OP code is no longer reproducible on recent version of data.table.